# White box around button Chrome

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am working on a website, I have this white border around my button when I click it. I'm using chrome, any idea why it's doing this and how to fix it ?

Comment: It looks like the focus ring (a.k.a. outline). **Do not remove it.** The focus ring is important for accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.button_class{
    outline:none; /* This is the point. When you clicked*/
}
```

Comment: This technically answers your question and you can do that, but it's bad. It's like "I don't like it that this orange light is blinking on my car when I put the indicator on. How can I switch off the orange light?". As D. Pardal has stated above, the focus indicator is very important for users that use different input methods than just tapping or clicking the button. If you don't like the white border, you should indicate in some other way that the button is focused.

Answer (score 2):

This is the focus ring (A.K.A. outline). **Don't remove it unless you have another way to indicate which element is focused!**

From the [Tests
CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 (CSS3 UI)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#outline-props):

> Keyboard users, in particular people with disabilities who may not be able to interact with the page in any other fashion, depend on the outline being visible on elements in the :focus state, thus authors **must not** make the outline invisible on such elements without making sure an alternative highlighting mechanism is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to three dots on your upper-right screen,and press settings,press advance, press accessability and turn off the "Show a quick highlight on the focus object"

Comment: While this does technically work, it only works on your machine and I'm not sure that's what OP wants.